# how to set json data to pinned header listview

Tags: android, json, listview, adapter, pinned-header-list-view

i'm using pinned header listview to set sticky headers on list view for that i'm using [this example](https://github.com/JimiSmith/PinnedHeaderListView). but the example contains som fixed data from adapter and i want to set data which is coming from api. and my json data look like below...

```
"diaryEntries": [
    {
      "diaryId": "1",
      "diaryEntryType": "test",
      "studentName": "testuser",
      "diaryText": "Please learn something and come tomorrow",
      "authorName": "test author",
      "authorRole": "testRole",
      "insert_ts": "2017-09-06T08:41:11.000Z",
      "update_ts": "2017-09-06T08:41:11.000Z"
    },
    {
      "diaryId": "2",
      "diaryEntryType": "test",
      "studentName": "testuser1",
      "diaryText": "Please learn something and come tomorrow",
      "authorName": "test author1",
      "authorRole": "testRole1",
      "insert_ts": "2017-09-06T08:41:11.000Z",
      "update_ts": "2017-09-06T08:41:11.000Z"
    }
  ]
```

and my adapter code is from link example is

```
public class TestSectionedAdapter extends SectionedBaseAdapter {

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int section, int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int section, int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int getSectionCount() {
        return 7;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCountForSection(int section) {
        return 15;
    }

    @Override
    public View getItemView(int section, int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LinearLayout layout = null;
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater) parent.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            layout = (LinearLayout) inflator.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
        } else {
            layout = (LinearLayout) convertView;
        }
        ((TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.textItem)).setText("Section " + section + " Item " + position);
        return layout;
    }

    @Override
    public View getSectionHeaderView(int section, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LinearLayout layout = null;
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater) parent.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            layout = (LinearLayout) inflator.inflate(R.layout.header_item, null);
        } else {
            layout = (LinearLayout) convertView;
        }
        ((TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.textItem)).setText("Header for section " + section);
        return layout;
    }

}
```

how to set json data in to pinned header list view and the headers are the "update_ts" from json object of list, can anyone help me to solve this?

Comment: Is that your response is JSON or GSon

Comment: response is in JSON

Comment: what you want to do exactly

Comment: i want to set json data into pinned header listview